Filter doesn't work when dynamically added column on primereact DataTable
I'm trying implement dynamic DataTable from PrimeReact, but added new column doesn't have filter data.
On example, there is dropdown and you can add more columns to table, but added column filter popup doesn't have any inputs for filtering
example on codesandbox
const DataTableEditDemo = () => {
  const [columnList, setColumnList] = useState(["code"]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MultiSelect
        value={columnList}
        options={columns}
        optionValue="field"
        optionLabel="header"
        onChange={(e) => setColumnList(e.value)}
      />
      <DataTable value={data} responsiveLayout="scroll">
        {columnList.map((val) => {
          return <Column key={val} field={val} header={val} filter />;
        })}
      </DataTable>
    </div>
  );
};

this is picture of working filter of loaded column by default
and when added new column from dropdown select, filter doesn't have menu UI neither data to filter out
I wonder if it's an UI library bug or am I missing out something. For my observation, useState should rerender this component, but I guess filter state doesn't updates.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
